# Why is Vue breaking my own code dom modifications?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I've got a class of mine, it's quite big so I cannot include it here, but essentially:

```
var MyClass = function(options) {
  this.options = {}
  this.options = $.extend(true,this.options,options);
  this.init();
}

MyClass.prototype = {
  init:function(){
    this.set_events();
  },

  set_events:function(){
    // attach some dom events that in turn alter the dom (change some data- properties)
  }
}
```

What is quite curious to me, is that IF I instantiate it after Vue, MyClass will work properly and it will be able to modify the dom as well will work.

```
var vueapp = new Vue({
  // init stuff
});

myclassinstance = new MyClass(); // OK
```

But, if I'll do the opposite:

```
myclassinstance = new MyClass(); // WILL NOT WORK (it won't be able to change data- properties upon dom events)

var vueapp = new Vue({
  // init stuff
});
```

Note #1: I've got no errors in console.

Note #2: Dom events get executed: I'm able to log from them and inspect dom elements, but it seems I cannot change their props!

So what? Anyone can explain me why this happens?

Comment: I normally use `export and import` to my custom function for vue ...

Comment: mmm, never used this technique, probably I'm not so much into this, can you explain some more please?

Comment: Hope this will help https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the DOM looks exactly the same after Vue initialization, **Vue has actually removed the original DOM and replace it with new DOM** with some Vue's settings/properties.

If you add the event listeners before Vue init, the DOM with event listener would be replaced with new DOM without event listener. That's why.

e.g. https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/LrvXyb

```
var appElem = document.getElementById("app");
console.log('before Vue init', appElem === document.getElementById("app"));
// true

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    message: "Hello world"
  }
});

console.log('after Vue init', appElem === document.getElementById("app"));
// false
```

Btw, modifying the DOM outside of Vue is always considered bad practice.

> Vue is a jealous library in the sense that you must let it completely
>   own the patch of DOM that you give it (defined by what you pass to
>   el). If jQuery makes a change to an element that Vue is managing, say,
>   adds a class to something, Vue won’t be aware of the change and is
>   going to go right ahead and overwrite it in the next update cycle.
>   https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

(jQuery or not, this is why modifying the DOM is bad)